# HTML select initial value not recognized

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a form on my page that has a few select, multiple, and simple. They are declared like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class = "col-sm-3 control-label">Tipo da Atividade</label>
    <div class = "col-sm-6">
        <p>
            <div class="bfh-selectbox" name="Ati_Tipo" id="Ati_Tipo" data-name="selectbox3" data-value="1" data-filter="true">
                <div data-value="1">Saídas Profissionais</div>
                <div data-value="2">Desporto</div>
                <div data-value="3">Cultura</div>
                <div data-value="4">Outros</div>
            </div>
        </p>     
    </div>                                    
</div>
```

They are working properly except in one situation. When I, for instance, enter the page, or refresh it, the select starts with the first option selected, as it should, and if I wanted that option I will not touch the select, because I already have the option I want selected. Although, when I submit, and try to get the value of the selected option I can't do it, it gives me an error. In order for it to work I need to open the select and click on the first option (the one which supposedly is already selected).

Note that I am using PHP, so to get the result I use the `$_POST` method.

Comment: you need the selected attribute on your option. but you aren't using options? or a select menu? if you aren't using the proper html elements you will have to handle the functionality yourself... which in that case just initialize whatever variable you are submitted to the first value via javasript: var selectMenuValue = 1;

Comment: _"it gives me an error"_. And that error would be...? I also see no form, select, or option elements. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: You should probably specify that you're using a JQuery plugin for forms. This isn't just standard Markup.